# How to get screen orientation without using the accelerometer?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

How to get it? In my XML file I use the only portrait orientation for my activity.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

and onConfigurationChanged and  does not work for orientation.

Upd currently I used:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        x = event.values[0];
        y = event.values[1];
    }

    private PictureOrientation getLastOrientation() {
        MyPictureOrientation orient;
        if (x >= -5 && x < 5) {
            if (y > 0) {
                orient = PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                orient = PORTRAIT_REV;
            }
        } else {
            if (x >= -10 && x < -5) {
                orient = LAND_RIGHT;
            } else {
                orient = LAND_LEFT;
            }
        }

        return orient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the current orientation:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: getResources().getConfiguration().orientation - always == 1

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code:

```
Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
if(getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight())
  // then you have portrait orientation
else
  // you have landscape
```

Comment: not for me. W and H for portrait orientation can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to work in potrait only put the following in manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and on oncreate and  on onConfigurationChanged put

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Does the page changed to landscape?
Try after removing 
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"